# Mongoose Model.update not working, but Model.findOneAndUpdate works

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

According to http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html the update method works as follows:

```
    MyModel.update(
        { user: { $in: [user_id]} },
        { $set : { dismissed: true } },
        { multi : true },
        function(err,na){

            console.log('err',err);
            console.log('na',na);

        }
    );
```

However I get this:

```
{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }
```

What is wrong here?
If I change **update** for **findOneAndUpdate** it works though.
Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I just changed multiple for multi as @jonasnas suggests but I still get the same result

Comment: Im using mongoose 4.0.4

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `multi` instead of `multiple` in the options and make sure `user_id` type is correct (`integer`/`string`)

Also in mongoose you need to get rid of `$set` in the second param

```
    MyModel.update(
        { user: { $in: [user_id]} },
        { dismissed: true },
        { multi : true },
        function(err,na){

            console.log('err',err);
            console.log('na',na);

        }
    );
```

Comment: I still get the same result, user_id is a Mongo ID string, isn't string the correct type ?

Comment: you might need to use `new ObjectId(uesr_id)` where `ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not going to work, in fact I get CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "user". Howerver why findOneAndUpdate works perfectly and update doesn't ?

Comment: also for debugging put a hardcoded value instead of user_id to make sure it has a correct value. Maybe your parameter is not what you think

Comment: Ok, looks like you don't need $set in update json. just put simple json

Comment: I'm still stuck with the same, changing to findOneAndUpdate makes it work. Sadly I need to update a group of entries not just one. Using a for loop seems wrong in many levels.

Comment: MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { user: { $in: [user_id]} },
        { dismissed: true },
        { multi : true },
        function(err,na){

            console.log('err',err);
            console.log('na',na);

        }
    );